# Xcode 12+ Simulator not attaching while running - Error

Tags: xcode, debugging, ios-simulator, xcode12

For some reason, while running xcode12 ++, unable to attach the simulator for debugging. Its disconnecting after installing.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

Quit Xcode.

run below command in terminal.

```
echo "settings set plugin.process.gdb-remote.packet-timeout 300" > .lldbinit
```

Restart system & restart xcode